# Sample size calculation when observations are subject to percent errors

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, measurement-error

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the required sample size for an experiment in which the observations are subject to measurement errors expressed as a percent value of the observation.

For the sake of simplicity assume that I want to do a 2-sample t-test on independent samples. I can calculate the required sample size easily enough when observations are subject to a fixed uncertainty (i.e., all observations having a fixed measurement error $e_{within}$, or equivalently a fixed measurement variance $\sigma^2_{within}$) by considering it as an additive error component and simply adding it to the between-observations variance, and then applying the usual sample size formulas using the total variance.

However, I'm stuck with the case of percent errors (i.e., when $e_{within}$ is set as a given percentage of the observed value). In this case each observation will have a different $\sigma^2_{within}$, with a linear relation between mean and variance for each observation.

Any pointers or ideas?

Comment: If your variables are subject to percent-errors a t-test may be less than ideal. You'd expect some skewness for example. What are you measuring?